# How to write a db_select query?

Tags: comments, database

How can I  write a query to do the following:

select cid, thread and paragraph_id(I have added this field to comment table) from comment table, and then sort them first based on the paragraph_id and  then based on thread. So for the comments that have the same paragraph_id they will be sorted by thread number.

Comment: I closed this as too broad, but we more than likely have similar duplicate questions. if someone wants to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look on the db_select documentation. I strongly reccomend on [this](https://api.drupal.org/comment/13489#comment-13489) comment.